# Ways to pass data from one page to another

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have scenario that I have to pass data from one page to another. Inorder to pass that currently I am using query string as shown below.

```
function showNextPage(Reference) {
    window.location.href = MasterPageVars.BaseUrl + 'Home/details?Reference=' + Reference;
}
```

This works fine. But now I want to pass multiple values such as from and to date values to next page. what I think is by passing them using query string is not appropriate.

I can get the data from database if I want. But it will require separate call to database. can someone point out some other methods that I can use here? I knew that I can use hiddenfor, session, and cookie too. What is the best way
?

Thanks.

Comment: Passing data in the querystring is absolutely fine, I can't think of a reason you'd think it's inappropriate. As you're using MVC you can setup routing if you'd prefer, but that's still passing data via the URL.

Comment: The only way to pass values to a GET method is using query string values (or route values)

Comment: For a few parameters that's fine, but too many, and not only do you create a really ugly url, but you risk throwing an exception because of the query string limit.

Comment: The only thing i can think off not wanting to use querystring is that the data is shown in the url. When used in public pc people can see the information used by previous users. 
There are multiple ways to fix this not using querystring. Are you sing .net core mvc?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I need to pass user entered datetime value from one page to another. Is it possible using query string? I think it is not.

Comment: @NishiShane of course you can

Comment: Yes of course - but it should to be passed in ISO (`yyyy-MM-dd`) format. But if this is a form where the user is entering a date, you can just use a form with `FormMethod.Get` and it will be passed automatically (you do not need a script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
        {
         <input type="datetime" name="date" placeholder="Type the date"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
           Submit
        </button>
}
```

After clicking the button, you'll pass the date you have typed just like this:
`http://yourhost.domain/Controller/Method?date=yy-mm-dd`

---

But take my advice, better use an `$.ajax` call, just because it is asynchronous and it won't redirect you to another page.

```
.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Controller/Method/',
            data: $('input').val(),
            success: function () {
                             }
});
```